# Firebase messaging, where to get Server Key?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase allows us to send notification messages via our own application by making `POST` request.

[This tutorial, gives to us instructions how to make this request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#auth). However, there is `Authorization` field in header where I must to place my own Server key.

Where I can get this Server key? There are no instructions for this.

Comment: https://support.clevertap.com/docs/android/how-to-find-your-gcm-sender-id-and-gcm-api-server-key.html

Comment: You can view bellow link. It has Spring java implementation
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172021/3073945

Comment: you can check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72378952/15739324

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Solution:

1. Click the **Settings (Cog wheel) icon** next to your project name at the top of the new Firebase Console, as per screenshot below:
   [image]
2. Click <kbd>Project settings</kbd>.
3. Click on the <kbd>Cloud Messaging</kbd> tab.
4. The key is right under <kbd>Server Key</kbd>. [image]

Comment: Hey @Frank Van Puffelen, is it the same thing? If i want it for Push Notifications where it says **"Get Application Server Keys"**. I am refering this link: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/#get_application_server_keys.

Comment: the key has a ... after it, which gives an impression that full key is not being shown here. Also it doesn't have a copy button like legacy server key. Can you kindly update your answer, so that users may know how to copy it.

Comment: There is currently a bug in the Firebase console that hides the Copy button in some browsers. A fix is in flight and should be released next week. In the meantime, left click on the Server key label and press Tab key as a workaround. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676388/firebase-dashboard-cant-see-full-server-key#comment76341929_44676388

Comment: hi, im trying to send notifcation to Both android and IOS from php, but the server is key is Different for both the apps, should i keep condition to take android's serverkey for android notifications and ios's key for ios messages?

Comment: It's not a tab, but the key is still there under the `Project credentials` heading on a row labeled `Server key`.

Comment: Is it possible to get this using the command line?  I don't see it anywhere in the API docs.

Comment: I can't even see the expected items, but instead I see Web Push Certificates.

Comment: It looks like they updated the UI recently, does anyone know where to find the Server Key in the new UI?

Comment: @DanielRead, please ref this link https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-a-google-server-api-key

Comment: @AshwinH thank you, I'll add this link to my answer for others to see

Answer (score 70):

**Updated UI June 2022**

I was able to get the Server key by doing the following steps:

1. Click on the "..." next to "Cloud Messaging API (Legacy)"
2. Click "Enable Cloud Messaging Api (Legacy)"
3. Go back to the previous page and refresh and you should now see the Server Key

Not sure if we need to do something different moving forward now that it's considered legacy....

Steps with images: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-a-google-server-api-key

**Update:**
Just putting this here in case it helps anyone since this thread gets a lot of activity. I was using **AWS SNS with Firebase** and I just updated all my apps to use the new Firebase Cloud Messaging API.

The migration from the old Server Key to the new token was very easy to implement:

- Go to the same location in Firebase where you got the server key
- Make sure Firebase Cloud Messaging API (v1) is enabled. If it's not, click on the three dots and enable it.
- Click on "Service Accounts" at the top
- Click "Generate new private key" & download the JSON file it provides.
- Go back to AWS SNS and update your application endpoint. In the place where you use to put the Server Key, now you will choose "Token" and upload the JSON File from Firebase.

Note: there is a lot of structural changes to the way your notifications should be structured now, however AWS SNS automatically upgrades your messages to the new format.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-fcm-v1-payloads.html#sns-fcm-v1-legacy-payload-structure

So for my case I didn't have to change anything about the message structure. If you want to use newer features you'll want to upgrade to the new structure

Migration guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

Comment: For me, after clicking "..." I also needed to click on the pop-up button to go to Google Cloud Console and then enable Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) there. After that, I returned to the tab with Project Settings (Cloud Messaging), refreshed the page and the key was there under the Legacy API section.

Answer (score 25):

July 2022

1. Click on the "..." (Positioned vertically) next to "Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) (DISABLED)" on your Firebase project settings.
2. Click on the pop-up menu listing. *It should say something like "Manage API in Google Cloud Console"

OnClick it will redirect to your google cloud console page, over there you should see an option to enable the Cloud Messaging API. Enable it and go back to your Firebase project settings and wallah, its there!

Comment: Wallahi It worked. :)

Comment: This one's the only one that worked

Comment: This is the only one that works in 2023

Answer (score 23):

enable that in 5 step

Go to `Firebase Console` > `Projects Settings` > `Cloud Messaging`

[image]

click on `Manage API in Google Cloud Console`

Go to `API Library` using the back button as shown below.

[image]

In the search bar, type `cloud messaging` and select `Cloud Messaging`

[image]

Click `Enable` to start using the `Cloud Messaging API`

[image]

Now Come Back `Projects Settings` > `Cloud Messaging`

Comment: Thanks, this works for September 2023

Answer (score 14):

Take this one: (First answer is right - this one is just to show how the page looks like!)
https://support.clevertap.com/docs/android/find-your-fcm-sender-id-and-fcm-server-api-key.html#

[image]

Comment: hi, im trying to send notifcation to Both android and IOS from php, but the server is key is Different for both the apps, should i keep condition to take android's serverkey for android notifications and ios's key for ios messages?

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE:** As of April 2017 this method does not work. The api_key in `google-services.json` is only the legacy key. The selected answer is correct.

---

**Deprecated way:**

In your project there is a JSON file called google-services.json

Open that file and search for

```
"api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "********"
        }
```

those *** are your  server api key

If you dont have that file then you can download it from your app details in firebase account

[image]

Comment: FYI, I just spent hours debugging push notification using "current_key" value. Not that I got this from your answer. Turns out you need to get the Servery Key the way the selected answer says.

Comment: Maybe your answer was right in the past but now (Feb. 2017) it is wrong. The selected answer is right!

Answer (score 9):

**Updated UI 2022**

Here are Steps to get serverKey

1. GO to [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
2. You can get view like this. if you have Created Project select project else Create new Project by click on Add project.
   [image]
3. Now you are in Project overview panel.
4. In Project overview panel in left upper corner click on settings button and go to Project Settings --> Cloud Messaging

[image]

5. That's it. in Project credentials Key and token are mentioned. Copy code and paste it. You are good to go
   [image]

Answer (score 9):

As of 2023, solution below works flawlessly:

1. Go to this link and enable: "Cloud Messaging" service:

> https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/googlecloudmessaging.googleapis.com

2. Go back to `Firebase Console` > `Projects Settings` > `Cloud Messaging`

You will see that Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) is now enabled and you can see your Server key there. That is it.

[image: firebase console project settings]

Comment: As for end of April 2023, the second part (Cloud messaging API) is not enabled and won't be anymore.

Answer (score 8):

There are two keys on firebase, the first one is in Settings (Tab General)
and its call Web API Key.

The second one and in what you are interesting for is in Settings (Tab Cloud Messaging) its called Server key

Use the second one for push notifications from php.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I did an integration with a 3rd party system and they asked for the "server key" json file.

They what I get it from firebase was:
Project Overview -> Project Settings -> Service accounts screen and A press the Generate new private key button.
I used that file and everything worked as expected

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was reading this after june 2023 and didn't want to use the legacy API.
So while reading https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1?hl=pt&authuser=0, I found a problem: "where is the access token?"

Here's how to get it

1. Click on your application settings button (gear icon)
2. Click on "Manage service accounts" link
3. Once you're on Google Cloud Console, click on your app's email
4. Go to keys tab > create key > add new key > select JSON
5. Done! That key that is now on your screen is your access token.