# How to send push notification from Firebase using google apps script?

Tags: android, firebase, google-apps-script, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to write a little script that tells Firebase to push notification if a certain condition is met. How to send push notification from Firebase using google apps script?

Comment: to make a valid question show us your research so far, attempts and what is failing.

Comment: It's the first time I try this, i don't know if it's possible, if it is, please give me  some resource so that I make an attempt

Comment: [Sending a notification message through Firebase Cloud Messaging requires calling a HTTP endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#http_post_request). [Calling external HTTP endpoints like that seems very feasible from Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external).

Answer (score 8):

I'd never tried this before, but it's actually remarkably simple.

There are two things you need to know for this:

1. [How to send a HTTP request to Firebase Cloud Messaging to deliver a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#http_post_request)
2. [How to call an external HTTP API from with Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external)

Once you have read those two pieces of documentation, the code is fairly straightforward:

```
function sendNotificationMessage() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'key=AAAAIM...WBRT'
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      notification: {
        title: 'Hello TSR!'
      },
      to: 'cVR0...KhOYB'
    })
  });
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

In this case:

1. the script sends a [notification message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications). This type of message:

   - shows up automatically in the system tray when the app is not active
   - is not displayed when the app is active

   If you want full control over what the app does when the message reaches the device, send a [data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages)
2. the script send the message to a specific device, identified by its device token in the `to` property. You could also send to a topic, such as `/topics/user_TSR`. For a broader example of this, see my blog post on [Sending notifications between Android devices with Firebase Database and Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html).
3. the `key` in the `Authorization` header will need to match the one for your Firebase project. See [Firebase messaging, where to get Server Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427709/firebase-messaging-where-to-get-server-key)

Comment: @TSR have you tried? Did you have a quick sample code?