# What is the Firebase code for android that will help send notification of a message?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need the android code for firebase that will send a notification when a user sends a message from one android phone.
eg: When I use Whats App for example if User A sends a message to User B, then a notification is sent to user B device when User B clicks on it, the page opens. How to do this via only firebase and no other server, I have searched all the Firebasse docs... In the notification only Server to device is given.. I am making a chat app and only this feature is remaining.

Comment: There is no Firebase API to send direct device to device notifications. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634046/is-it-possible-to-send-pushnotifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-t. I've written about one way to accomplish the use-case, but it requires a trusted process. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html  You could also send them from Apps Script (which runs on Google's servers). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174372/how-to-send-push-notification-from-firebase-using-google-apps-script/42179497#42179497

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://myapptemplates.com/simple-android-chat-app-tutorial-firebase-integration/) code and customize as per your need... i also used this code to customize my chatting application

You have to add notification code inside the following method in Chat.java class

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages").addListenerForSingleValueEvent();`

...*And if you want to receive notifications when your app is not running or close like whatsapp. You have to create an android service for notification that will run continuously in the background.*

Comment: This what I meant What does the Conversation class do?

Comment: As u can see there are variables sender, receiver, message etc..  the class instance hold the ids of sender and receiver and also the message and status(delivered or not) of a specific conversation