# Firebase dashboard can't see full server key

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

When looking at my server key in the Firebase dashboard, the server key is cut off and I'm not sure how to see the entire string:

[image]

The `Legacy server key` has a copy button I can use, but the new server key does not.

**How can I copy or see my full new server key?**

Comment: *firebaser here* Vishu's answer works. But that indeed is a bug. I'll report.

Comment: I too am having this problem...and more. My additional issues are iOS App section just spins and spins and my IDs suddenly changed on me. Documented here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741392/firebase-console-broken-and-the-senderid-server-keys-all-changed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just left click on the *Server key* label and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. There you will see a <kbd>Copy</kbd> option. Click it and you now will have the key

Comment: After pressing Tab, there's a small copy icon. Use that to copy.