# Firebase console broken and the senderID, server keys all changed

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, google-developers-console

I created my Firebase app, created all the senderIDs & server key for Cloud Messaging.  I tested and everything worked.  That was last week.

This week I am doing more testing and getting an error returned to my php script: `{ ["error"]=> string(13) "NotRegistered" }`

I log back in to Firebase, go to Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging and see **BOTH** the server key and the sender ID have changed.  As well, the iOS linked app section just spins and spins and never loads that section.  I haven't done anything.  Is anyone else experiencing this?  How can I get this fixed?  I can't even see the full Server Key...and when I tried linking the new senderID back to my Play Store Developer App Console it errored out saying "invalid senderID".  Thus I don't even think the new senderID and server keys will work...but at the same time, the ones I was using are not working now either.

Comment: The fact that the server key is hidden was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44676388) and should be fixed early next week. The other issues sound new to me. I suggest you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - thanks for that.  Sounds like there is more to the bug then just being able to copy the key.  I have opened a case with Firebase support, uploaded screen shots...but the iOS issue spinning indefinitely ...and the senderID not a valid FCM API Key back in the app "services and apis" in Play Developer Console - its like my Firebase project/app is in some kind of hung state and while it is its keys/IDs aren't valid/working.

Comment: After looking around a bit more, I saw in the `Project Settings -> Account Linking` section that the `Googe Play` section had no linked apps.  I clicked on "Manage Linking" and see my listed app is not liked, the but `?` next to "not linked" pops up a msg "add this SHA1 in your apps settings".  I clicked that to add then back under the `Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging the iOS section now appears.  The senderID and server key are different again but at least it now looks like it supposed to...will report back with results.

Comment: It took the server key on the Google Play Store app link section...going to test a few push notifications now.

Comment: Hmm... the most common cause of this type of problem is a browser plugin (e.g. an ad blocker) blocking traffic from Firebase. If that's not the case, reporting the issue details to support is your best option. There's not a lot we can do about it here.