# Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1): Server Key missing

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging

We're using *Urban Airship* to send push messages to our Android app.

In that process, we need to configure *Airship* with '***Server Key***' provided in *Firebase Console -> Cloud Messaging*.

As recommended there, we are trying to migrate from GCM to FCM.

The problem is that '***Server Key***' is missing in '*Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1)*' configuration.
It is still available in '*Cloud Messaging API (Legacy)*' configuration, but migration is suggested.

Following the links in FCM configuration didn't help too much with this issue.

[image: Firebase Console - Cloud Messaging]

Answer (score 22):

Firebase cloud messaging is now shifted to API (V1)

So to get the `serverkey` you should enable the cloud messaging API (Legacy).

Follow the steps:

1. Click on the three dots and click on manage Api in google cloud console
   [image]
2. Click on enable.
   [image]

3.Now redirect back to the main page and refresh the page.

Now you have your `serverkey`

Comment: Wow, it sure took a long time to find this! Thank you! This was the only key that Amazon SNS would accept.

Comment: This also worked for Intercom as well, thank you

Comment: Can't believe it is that easy and yet that make it so hard to find it.

Answer (score 9):

To access the server key:

1. Open Project Settings as you already did
2. Open the Firebase Cloud Messaging API menu (to the right of the **Enabled**)
3. Click on Manage API in Google Cloud Console, it will redirect you to Google Cloud Platform
4. In Google Cloud Platform, you will get Firebase Cloud Messaging API, click on Manage. It will redirect you to APIs & Services
5. Click on Credentials (on the left side of the screen)
6. There you will get different tables. One is called API Keys and inside you will see an entry called Server Key
7. Click on Show Key, and you will get what you want

I hope this will help you

Comment: For me it shows iOS key (auto created by Firebase), Android key (auto created by Firebase) and Browser key (auto created by Firebase). There is no such thing as a "Server Key". All 3 keys result in a Error 401, PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED.

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Any solution? there is No Server Key under this section. Only Android key & Browser Key

Comment: There is no such thing as "Server key". Only Android key & Browser Key

Comment: Not able to find the Server key. Any idea on this?.

Comment: Any solution? there is no server key under this section.

Answer (score 7):

From Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1), we have to enable the cloud messaging service.

1. Open project settings
2. Select three dot menu right to Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) and tap Manage API in Google Cloud Console
3. In the redirected Google Cloud Console enable the cloud messaging service.
4. Go back to project settings and refresh. You can get the server key now.

Reference - https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-a-google-server-api-key

Comment: We already have both enabled and the key for the Legacy one (the one referenced in that document).
The problem is that we cannot get the key for the V1 one.
The server key we're using (Legacy) is working fine for now, but we don't know how long it will be, since they encourage to migrate to the V1.

Comment: @abeljus Did you found a solution with V1?