# Worksuite CRM Web to Android Synchronization

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the worksuit crm web version and also android version which is built with Laravel Framework . In my crm , i have bought a plugin called rest api module . In that rest api module , i need to enter an fcm key which pushes notifications to android app .

please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Where is your code? What you have tried so far? Where do you stack?

Comment: Are you asking where to find the FCM server key? If so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337512/where-can-i-find-the-api-key-for-firebase-cloud-messaging and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71763866/firebase-cloud-messaging-api-v1-server-key-missing

Comment: No , The thing is i have Worksuite crm app and I bought a plugin in called rest api module for that crm . the plugin  enables you to control your Worksuite crm app via mobile and ios . The worksuite crm is also available in Playstore and app store .  But in that rest api module it is asking a fcm key for testing push notifications for android and ios . How can i do that ?